# Is this grammatically correct please?

Tags: grammar, implication

I know that if I say
"I was not feeling well last week, I am okay this week" it is both complete and grammatically correct.

Is this correct as well?
"I was not feeling well last week, I am okay this" - I do not say the week word after this - is that a complete and grammatically correct sentence?

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: It would be perfectly understandable in informal conversation. It probably wouldn't be appropriate in a formal situation ('okay' wouldn't be either!).

Comment: No. That wouldn't really work. In your sentence "this" is acting as a determiner which needs to be followed by a noun.  It can't work as a pronoun here. If you don't want to repeat the word "week", you could say "I wasn't feeling well last week, but I 'm fine now".

Comment: thanks Billy, your explanation makes a lot of sense

Comment: @RohitRana - sorry, I typed an extra space in the contraction by mistake. It should be **I'm**

Comment: I was not feeling well last week **but** I am okay this week. Very simple. For your information, please read the HELP page at the top right of your screen.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this sentence must include a proper conjunction between "week" and "I" because a comma alone does not work in this case. You could use the word "but" after the comma, a different conjunction after the comma, or use a semicolon instead of a comma. An easy way to determine this is to check if each part of the sentence could be its own sentence independently. In this example "I was not feeling well last week." and "I am okay this week." can also be independent sentences. Therefore, to use them both in one sentence you must include a comma with a conjunction or a semicolon.

In the context of your sentence, the word "this" is being used as an adjective. Therefore, it must have a noun or pronoun which it describes. The second sentence is grammatically incorrect because it cannot describe the previously used "week" because it is in a separate clause and "last week" must be stated separately from "this week". Therefore, you must again say "this week" since it is needed be described by the adjective and to clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: I agree that a comma isn't up to the job here. Either a conjunction, such as ***but***, or start a new sentence (where that second sentence might reasonably *end* with ***,though***).